# Printing warning: “hpPostScriptPDE.plugin” will damage your computer

Tags: macbook-pro, printing, driver, big-sur

Network Printer: **HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125ra**

After updating to latest Catalina MacOS / MacOS BigSur 11.0.1,
when I try printing i received warning:

> “hpPostScriptPDE.plugin” will damage your computer.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to be more specific in regards of what the question is.

Comment: Delete the printer drivers and re-install.

Comment: HP had a certificate expired a couple of weeks ago. Check with them whether they've fixed it yet.

Comment: @Allan, can you describe, how to safely to remove printer?

Comment: @mature This link has an uninstaller https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06960563 HOWEVER, the HP site doesn’t have drivers for any OS greater than 10.9 for my printer, so be sure to check to see if there is a version for yours before uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating to Catalina 10.15.7 on my older Mac Mini. To fix the printing warning (and allow printing) I first deleted the HP drivers and then installed new ones. My HP Color LaserJet 2025 wasn’t one of the options with the new drivers but the OS selected Laserjet CP2020 and it seems to work fine. If nothing comes up that looks close to your printer, you could try “generic laser printer”.

You can download the uninstaller at HPs site:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06960563

I found the new drivers on Apple’s site:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1888?locale=en_US

My Mac is too old to install Big Sur and My wifes’s doesn’t have enough space so I can’t test it with Big Sur.

I don’t think it is a problem with HPs certificates as Allan said since the same printer works fine on my laptop running 10.6.8.

Comment: Cool solution to clear MacOS, thanks. But You are right **HP Printer Drivers v5.1 for OS X** isn't work with Big Sur 11.01.

Comment: @mature I just got my M1 Mac Mini and the HP drivers won’t even attempt to install.  I set up the printer with Bonjour and the generic drivers will allow me to save as PDF and seem to work fine for printing.

Comment: The HP Uninstaller got stuck for me. Have been waiting for an hour now. Did anyone else have this problem?